# Duda sobre comando de procesos

Tags: linux, proceso

¿Cómo puedo mostrar todos los procesos que estén corriendo en el sistema, como si fueran
ficheros?

Es una pregunta que tengo en una práctica y me tiene de vuelta y media.

He mirado el manual del comando ps y no viene nada similar.

---

A ver, yo había encontrado el comando lsof, que en teoría sólo muestra ficheros, pero no sé si sería lo correcto.

Comment: no entiendo lo de que "como si fueran ficheros". ¿No te vale `ps aux`?

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te sugerimos revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Revisar al buen `/proc` (el directorio) te puede ser de ayuda. No es un comando, es un pseudo-sistema de archivos que toma a `/proc` como punto de montaje. Con esto puedes ver los procesos como ficheros.

Puedes revisarlo con:

```
ls -l --color /proc
```

Por ejemplo, crea un proceso con un nombre personalizado (para que se vea guay).

```
bash -c "exec -a proceso1 sleep 9999 &"
```

que hace un `sleep` por 9999 segundos en segundo plano y lo llama "proceso1", esto lo puedes ver usualmente con `ps -fea` o `ps aux` como sugirió @fedorqui (o con `htop`, como sea).

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
(...)
cuau        45  0.0  0.0  57024   664 tty2     S    07:03   0:00 proceso1 9999
(...)
```

Nota que en mi ejemplo el PID es 45. Puedes seleccionar únicamente la información del proceso con ese nombre ("proceso1", o como tú le quieras llamar) con:

```
ps -f --pid=$(pgrep -f proceso1)
```

Pero con el simple `pgrep -f proceso1` puedes tener su **PID** que eso es lo que necesitaremos.

Dale un `ls -l --color` al directorio `/proc` y te aparecerán directorios cuyos nombres son los **PID**'s de los procesos que estan corriendo. Por ejemplo, en mi caso me aparecen estos:

```
ls -l --color /proc
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root 0 Apr 24 07:03 1
dr-xr-xr-x 7 cuau cuau 0 Apr 24 07:03 2
dr-xr-xr-x 7 cuau cuau 0 Apr 24 07:13 224
dr-xr-xr-x 7 cuau cuau 0 Apr 24 07:03 3
dr-xr-xr-x 7 cuau cuau 0 Apr 24 07:03 45
...
```

Y justamente el número 45 es el que acabo de crear. Puedes investigar (con `ls` o `cat` a los archivos dentro esa carpeta en `/proc` con el PID (hint: investiga con `cat` sobre el contenido de los archivos `comm` y `cmdline`)) sobre lo que hay dentro de esa carpeta (la que se llama como el número de PID) para convencerte de que se trata de todo lo referente a un proceso y que esa carpeta tiene la información sobre los procesos corriendo en el kernel.

Citando de `proc(5)`:

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
> The proc filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel 
> data structures. It is commonly mounted at /proc.  Most of it is read-only, but some
> files allow kernel variables to be changed.
> ```